# Can I use words like "Facebook", "Twitter" in my site navigation?

Tags: seo, copyright, navigation, trademark

I have a website where one section of website has top menu links in this manner

```
<li><a href=../memes/index.php>MEMES</a></li>
<li><a href=../facebook/index.php>FB</a></li>
<li><a class=active href=../twitter/index.php>TWITTER</a></li>
<li><a href=../youtube/index.php>YOUTUBE</a></li>
<li><a href=../quora/index.php>QUORA</a></li>
<li><a href=../people/index.php>PEOPLE</a></li>
```

Can it be problem problem with trademark or copyright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to use trademarked terms on your website providing you cannot be perceived as [passing yourself off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_off) as that company...

Simply linking to websites using the brand name as the anchor is certainly no cause for concern.

Comment: I am not actually linking to the sites. When a user clicks on let's say Facebook , he visits a page on my own site but it has content related to Facebook.

Comment: Yes, that is also fine. Providing you aren't making out to your audience that they are on Facebook, there is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may add links on your site to your Facebook profile, YouTube page, etc. In that case, this is not a problem of copyright. You may add them if you want to.